# pandas - Changing the format of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a data frame which is of the format:

```
level_0 level_1 counts
0   back    not_share   1183
1   back    share   1154
2   back    total   2337
3   front   not_share   697
4   front   share   1073
5   front   total   1770
6   left    not_share   4819
7   left    share   5097
8   left    total   9916
9   other   not_share   2649
10  other   share   2182
11  other   total   4831
12  right   not_share   1449
13  right   share   1744
14  right   total   3193
```

I want to convert this form to

```
level_0 share not_share total
back    1154  1183      2337
front   1073  697       1770
```

and so on..

Is there any method that I can use or should I convert it into a native Python datatype and then do the manipulations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `sum`

```
df.groupby(['level_0', 'level_1']).counts.sum().unstack()
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, it's an interesting (unusual) method!

Comment: @MaxU for smaller `df`s, this seems to be quicker.  For much larger (millions of rows) both methods seem to even out.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [101]: df.pivot_table(index='level_0', columns='level_1', values='counts', aggfunc='sum')
Out[101]:
level_1  not_share  share  total
level_0
back          1183   1154   2337
front          697   1073   1770
left          4819   5097   9916
other         2649   2182   4831
right         1449   1744   3193
```